# Which thread listens to a specific UDP port

Tags: linux, multithreading, udp, netstat, lsof

I ran:

```
# lsof | grep 10900
```

And its output:

```
MyExecutab 103497        myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103498 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103499 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103500 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103501 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103502 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900 
MyExecutab 103497 103503 myuser    7u     IPv4             985833       0t0        UDP my.example.com:10900
```

I am trying to figure out which thread is reading from the UDP port 10900.

It seems like there are 7 threads reading from that port, is it true?

I feel that only one thread is actually reading but lsof just listed all child threads (within the same process) and the parent thread.

`netstat -plun` shows that only the parent thread (PID) is listening to that port:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 10.7.168.173:10900      0.0.0.0:*                           103497/MyExecutable
```

I also checked `/proc/[pid]/fd`.  Because only 103497 is a PID, the rest are TID, so `/proc/` only has 103497 but not the rest.

So is there really a way to figure out which thread listens to a specific UDP port?

I am on CentOS 7 (kernel 3.10).

Thanks!

Comment: Any number of threads can call `recvfrom/sendto` on the same UDP socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `strace -ffp <pid>` and see which threads use file descriptor 7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What does `-ff` do?  Manpage says, `-ff         If the -o filename option is in effect, each processes trace is written to filename.pid where pid is the numeric process id of each process.  This is incompatible with -c, since no per-process counts are kept.`  which doesn't really tell me much.  Same as `-f`?  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF If you try it you will see tid in front of each syscall.